# react native webview right to left language components shown with mirror writing ios 17

Tags: react-native, webview, localization, ios17

I have an application in react native that includes a web-view, the content of the web view is in Hebrew (a right-to-left language), on iOS 17 I get a strange result,
And all the lists were shown as mirror writing, also open file input dialog box in mirror writing, and when long press input I also get mirror writing.
Any help?
Screenshots attached
[input text mirror writing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nbb2t.png), [input file mirror writing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xeK5A.png), [select mirror writing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MkKTs.png)

react native code:

```
 <WebView ref={webViewRef} source={{ html: `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="rtl" lang="he">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>

<h1>דף נסיון</h1>

<p>דוגמא לקומבו</p>
<form action="/action_page.php">
  <label for=”cars">בחר צבע</label>
  <select name="cars" id="cars">
    <option value="volvo">ירוק</option>
    <option value="saab">כחול</option>
    <option value="opel">אדום</option>
    <option value="audi">צהוב</option>
  </select>
  <br><br>

<label for=”myfile">דוגמא לקובץ</label>
<br><br>
<input type="file" id="myfile" name=“myfile">
<br><br>

<label for=”text1">דוגמא לטקסט</label>
<br><br>
<input type="text" id="text1" name="text1" placeholder="נסיון">
<br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>` }} onError={onWebViewError} onLoadStart={onWebViewLoadStart} onLoadEnd={onWebViewLoadEnd}
                onShouldStartLoadWithRequest={onShouldStartLoadWithRequest} originWhitelist={['http://*', 'https://*', 'intent://*', 'tel:*', 'WebBrowser:*', 'webbrowser:*']}
                onNavigationStateChange={(navState) => { setCanGoBack(navState.canGoBack) }} sharedCookiesEnabled={true} 
                mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction={false} javaScriptEnabled={true} nativeConfig={{props: {webContentsDebuggingEnabled: true}}}/>
```

It does not reproduce on other versions of iOS.

Answer (score 0):

To render HTLM & seamlessly change the content LTR and RTL in react native use can use combination of `react-native-render-html` and `react-native-webview`

1.install both packages;

```
yarn add react-native-render-html react-native-webview
```

2.render html in webview

```
import RenderHTML from 'react-native-render-html';
import WebView from 'react-native-webview';

<RenderHTML
   renderers={{iframe: IframeRenderer}}
   WebView={WebView}
   renderersProps={{autoplay: true}}
   customHTMLElementModels={{
   iframe: iframeModel,
    }}
   source={{
   html: `<iframe width=${wp('85%')} height='250' src=${source)} 
   </iframe>`}}
   contentWidth={wp('100%')}
   tagsStyles={{
   body: {
   textAlign: language === 'Arabic' ? 'left' : '',
    },
   }}
 />
```

3.explanation

```
tagsStyles={{
   body: {
    : language === 'Arabic' ? 'left' : '',
    },
  }}
```

tagsStyle painless switch the content based on your language.
As I'm using Arabic and English. when arabic language is selected content automatically change to RLT and vice versa.